# When writing json with File.open do I need to set the headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am pulling a json file from my project and then writing it as a static file in a javascript directory like so:

```
json_file_path = Rails.root.join("data", "infographics.json")
json_object = JSON.parse(open("http://url/api/infographics/all").read)
File.open(json_file_path, 'w') {|f| f.write(json_object.to_json) }
```

But when I go to read this file from my dev machine to the remote server I get an error of:

```
Origin http://0.0.0.0:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Is this an apache setting or am I not setting my header correctly when I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header like this:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`

in `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>`, `<VirtualHost>` or `.htaccess`

Comment: Just a note: This makes your data accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've used a diferent IP or domain name from the address you call it to access the resources. Eg.: being in `http://localhost:3000` and trying to access `http://0.0.0.0:3000` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000`